# Compare two DataFrames and output a new DataFrame with the different index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two different DataFrames and i wanna get a new DataFrame with the indexes that are different.

DataFrame A:

```
Name Color
Jony Blue
Mike Red
Joanna Green
```

DataFrame B:

```
Name Color
Jony Blue
Mike Red
```

DataFrame Output:

```
Name Color
Joanna Green
```

How can i do to get this DataFrame Output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `drop_duplicates`

```
import pandas as pd
dataA = {'Name':['Jony', 'Mike', 'Joanna'], 'Color':['Blue', 'Red', 'Green']}
dataB = {'Name':['Jony', 'Mike'], 'Color':['Blue', 'Red']}

dfA = pd.DataFrame(dataA)
dfB = pd.DataFrame(dataB)

df = pd.concat([dfA, dfB]).drop_duplicates(keep=False, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: I thought about this method, but realized the author specifically asked about matching Indexes, not fully matching rows~

Comment: You can limit `drop_duplicates` to the subset you want. The only drawback of this approach is if you have duplicates unique to one of the dataframe and want to keep them in the output.

Comment: How would you select the index as the subset for `drop_duplicates`?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using 'symmetric difference' on a set that you convert to a Series of df ?

```
dfc=pd.DataFrame()

dfc['Name Color']=pd.Series(list(set(dfa['Name Color']).symmetric_difference(set(dfb['Name Color']))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the Name Column is the index in both dataframes:

```
df_a = pd.DataFrame({'Color': {'Jony': 'Blue', 'Mike': 'Red', 'Joanna': 'Green'}})
df_a = df_a.rename_axis('Name')
df_b = pd.DataFrame({'Color': {'Jony': 'Blue', 'Mike': 'Red'}})
df_b = df_b.rename_axis('Name')

df = pd.concat([df_a[~df_a.index.isin(df_b.index)], df_b[~df_b.index.isin(df_a.index)]])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
        Color
Name         
Joanna  Green
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to `outer-merge` with the `indicator` parameter set to True. Then the common rows will be flagged "both" and since you don't want the common rows, you filter them out:

```
out = df1.merge(df2, how='outer', indicator=True).query('_merge!="both"').drop(columns='_merge')
```

Output:

```
     Name  Color
2  Joanna  Green
```